# Impact of reducing HDFS replication factor to 2 (or just one) on HBase map/reduce performance

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hbase, apache-phoenix

What is the impact of reducing HDFS replication factor to 2 (or just one) on HBase map/reduce performance ? I am having a HBase cluster hosted on Azure VMs with data stored in azure managed disks. Azure managed disk itself keeps 3 copies of the data for fault tolerance, so thinking of reducing the HDFS replication factor to save on storage overhead. Given that map reduce jobs make use of local availability of the data to avoid data transfer over network, wondering anyone has any information on  the impact on map reduce performance if there just one replica of the data available?

Answer (score 2):

This is a difficult question to answer as it depends greatly on what workloads you run.

By decreasing the replication factor, you can speed up the performance of write operations, since the data is written to fewer DataNodes. However, as you noted, you may have decreased locality since it can be more difficult to find a node which has a replica and has free space to execute a task.

Keeping only a single replica can have strong implications on the impact of a single node failure. If a single node dies, all of its data will be unavailable until you restart a new node with the same Azure managed disks. If there are multiple HDFS replicas, data availability is maintained throughout.

Running HDFS DataNodes on top of Azure managed disks sounds like a bit of a bad idea. In addition to breaking some of the core HDFS assumptions ("my disk might fail at any time"), it seems unlikely that you have true data locality if your data is stored in three replicas. I wonder if you have considered:

- Using a non-managed disk service. Does Azure provide a way to use a disk which is not replicated? This is much closer to how HDFS is intended to be used.

  - Storing data in Azure storage (WASB or ADLS) instead of HDFS. This is more "cloud native" way of running things. If you find that performance is lacking, you can use HDFS for intermediate data and only store final data in Azure. HDFS also provides a way to cache data from external storage systems by using [Provided Storage](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsProvidedStorage.html).